# Jackson ObjectMapper writeValueAsBytes method adds another backslash to a string that already contains backslash

Tags: java, json, jackson, jersey, jax-rs

Using Jacksons's ObjectMapper if I try to convert a string that already contains a backslash to byte array, and later change that byte array back to string, the output contains an extra backslash. The following code shows the problem

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("id", "Test\\String");

    //output: data[id] that has single backslash: Test\String
    System.out.println("data[id] that has single backslash: " + data.get("id"));

    byte[] dataInBytes = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(data);
    //output: data in bytes that contains double backslash: {"id":"Test\\String"}
    System.out.println("data in bytes that contains double backslash: " + new String(dataInBytes, "UTF-8"));
}
```

Is there a way to configure the ObjectMapper such that mapper#writeValueAsBytes method does not change the string Test\String to Test\\String? Is there any other way using Jackson/ObjectMapper to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is valid behaviour. The output has **escaped back-slashes**. In JSON, the backslash has to be escaped.

In other words, `{"id":"Test\String"}` is not valid JSON.

Check [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html) for other characters that have to be escaped in JSON.